# Error in sudo apt-get remove -f

Tags: sudo, dpkg, plymouth

I have installed kernel 3.18.2 with Cinnamon on Ubuntu 14.04.1:

```
john@john-G31M-S2C:~$ sudo apt-get remove -f
[sudo] password for john: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libvte-common libvte9 plymouth-x11
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  plymouth
Suggested packages:
  desktop-base
The following packages will be upgraded:
  plymouth
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1320 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 204 kB of archives.
After this operation, 388 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  plymouth
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Get:1 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main plymouth i386 0.9.0-9 [204 kB]
Fetched 204 kB in 7s (26.3 kB/s)                                               
(Reading database ... 175784 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../plymouth_0.9.0-9_i386.deb ...
Unpacking plymouth (0.9.0-9) over (0.8.8-0ubuntu17) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/plymouth_0.9.0-9_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libply.so.2.1.0', which is also in package libplymouth2:i386 0.8.8-0ubuntu17
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/plymouth_0.9.0-9_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
john@john-G31M-S2C:~$
```

Comment: What's the question here?

Answer (score 1):

So, dpkg is trying to overwrite `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libply.so.2.1.0`, which is already there and brought by the package `libplymouth2:i386`. My suggestion is to uninstall `libplymouth2:i386` first, then run `sudo apt-get remove -f` and afterwords again install the package you jsut uninstalled.

Hopefully that will help.

Answer (score 0):

The main error is "The following packages cannot be authenticated". So try with the following,

```
sudo apt-key update
sudo apt-get update
```

Hope this will help you to fix the issue.

Comment: Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org unstable/main Translation-en_US                   
Fetched 6,784 kB in 2min 40s (42.4 kB/s)                                       
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://ftp.us.debian.org unstable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553